# I have rendered some dummy data from an array but when i try to update it and then render it dynamically, it goes wrong. I have the code here below

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have  started learning React.js and i have covered basic concepts like React States, working and events.
just encountered a problem in rendering my data on the screen dynamically
here is the code.

**Description: I am trying to create a very small SPA in which the user can enter the name of expense(title), the amount spent(amount), and the date of expense(date).
the user can then add these expenses using the add expense button and it should then be updated as a new expense component in the SPA.**

**problem: The dummy data(static data from an array) is rendered on the screen.
when I try to add a new expense, this new expense is displayed with the title from the DUMMY_DATA array.**

**what I want: whenever a user enters a new expense, then this new expense should be added with the entered data, not from DUMMY_DATA.**

```
----APP.JS-----

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Expenses from "./components/Expenses/Expenses";
import NewExpense from "./components/NewExpense/NewExpense";
const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
{
 id: "e1",
title: "Toilet Paper",
amount: 94.12,
date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
},
{ id: "e2", title: "New TV", amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
{ 
id: "e3",
title: "Car Insurance",
amount: 294.67,
date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
},
{
id: "e4",
title: "New Desk (Wooden)",
amount: 450,
date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
 },
 ];
const App = () => {
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);

const addExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
setExpenses((previousExpenses) => {
  return [expense, ...previousExpenses];
 });
 };
  return (
 <div>
  <NewExpense onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler} />
  <Expenses items={expenses} />
   </div>
    );
      };

     export default App;
```

-----NEW EXPENSE------

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./NewExpense.css";
 import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseForm";
 const NewExpense = (props) => {
 const saveExpenseDataHandler = (enteredExpenseData) => {
 const expenseData = { ...enteredExpenseData, id: Math.random().toString() };
 console.log("------new expense-------");
 console.log(expenseData);
 props.onAddExpense(expenseData);
   };

   return (
  <div className="new-expense">
  <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler} />
  </div>
    );
     };
      export default NewExpense;
```

------EXPENSES------

```
 import "./Expenses.css";
 import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
 import Card from "../UI/Card";
 import ExpensesFilter from "./ExpensesFilter";

  const Expenses = (props) => {
  const filterChangeHandler = (selectedYear) => {
   console.log("in expenses.js");
  console.log(selectedYear);
   };
  return (
  <div>
  <Card className="expenses">
    <ExpensesFilter onChangeFilter={filterChangeHandler} />

    {props.items.map((expense) => (
      <ExpenseItem
        title={expense.title}
        amount={expense.amount}
        date={expense.date}
      />
    ))}
  </Card>
   </div>
     );
    };
    export default Expenses;
```

------EXPENSE FORM------

```
import "./ExpenseForm.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ExpenseForm = (props) => {
const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");
const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState("");
const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("");

const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
// console.log(event.target.value);
};
const amoundChangeHandeler = (event) => {
setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);
};
const dateChangeHandeler = (event) => {
setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
};

const submitHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const expenseData = {
  title: enteredTitle,
  amount: enteredAmount,
  date: new Date(enteredDate),
};

console.log("--------expense form---------");
console.log(expenseData);
props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);

setEnteredTitle("");
setEnteredAmount("");
setEnteredDate("");
};
return (
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
  <div className="new-expense__controls"></div>
  <div className="new-expense__control "></div>
  <label className="new-expense__control label">Title</label>
  <input type="text" value={enteredTitle} onChange={titleChangeHandler} />

  <div className="new-expense__controls"></div>
  <div className="new-expense__control"></div>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <input
    type="number"
    value={enteredAmount}
    min="0.01"
    step="0.01"
    onChange={amoundChangeHandeler}
    />

  <div className="new-expense__controls"></div>
  <div className="new-expense__control"></div>
  <label>Date</label>
  <input
    type="date"
    value={enteredDate}
    min="2019-01-01"
    max="2022-12-31"
    onChange={dateChangeHandeler}
  />

  <div className="new-expense__actions">
    <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
  </div>
   </form>
   );
  };
   export default ExpenseForm;
```

------EXPENSE ITEM------

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
import ExpenseDate from "./ExpenseDate";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);

const clickHandeler = () => {
setTitle("Updated!");
 };

 return (
 <Card className="expense-item">
  <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
  <div className="expense-item__description">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
  </div>
  <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
  <button onClick={clickHandeler}>Change Title</button>
  </Card>
   );
  };
  export default ExpenseItem;
```

here are some snapshots.

1-> initial state
[this is the initial state after saving the code and opening it in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyCBg.png)

2-> [here is the data i am going to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHMSp.png)

3->[error state. i want a a new expense to be formed(abcd) and to show the title amount and date with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpmOL.png)

Comment: Consider editing your question to add a description of the problem.

Comment: @johnH description added

Answer (score 0):

------EXPENSES------

syntax error in rendering title in  block
it is props.title instead of just title

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
   import ExpenseDate from "./ExpenseDate";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);

const clickHandeler = () => {
setTitle("Updated!");
   };

 return (
 <Card className="expense-item">
 <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
 <div className="expense-item__description">
 <h2>{props.title}</h2>
  </div>
  <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
  <button onClick={clickHandeler}>Change Title</button>
  </Card>
   );
   };
  export default ExpenseItem;
```